# os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) not working correctly in PowerShell or cmd?

Tags: python, powershell, cmd, sublimetext3, os.path

I have a function runs correctly when built from my editor (Sublime Text 3), but incorrectly when run from Command Prompt or PowerShell (although no errors are thrown, very frustrating to debug!).

The goal of my misbehaving function, `cdhome()`, is to set the current working directory to the directory of the running Python script.

```
import os

def cdhome():
    return os.chdir(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

The problem is that the `os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` portion does not behave as expected:

1. In Sublime Text 3, I get the correct directory path.
2. In Cmd/PowerShell, I get the directory path of the parent of the parent directory.

Why is the behavior different? How do I get Cmd/PowerShell to behave like Sublime Text 3?

Comment: What's the value of `__file__` and what's the return value of `os.getcwd()` after the `chdir` call?

Comment: Interesting... In Sublime Text, `__file__` gives me the full file path, from `C:` to the file. In PowerShell, `__file__` give me *just* the file and its extension, no path information. Caveat, I am checking this with a `print()` statement, so I don't know what the `__repr__` really is.

Comment: The same goes for cmd, filename and extension, nothing else.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you are running into, but Powershell maintains its own CWD, separately from the process CWD. So if a program running within PS calls the OS to get CWD, it won't necessarily be the same as what `get-location` returns.

Comment: @MichaelMolter, `__file__` for the main script is relative to the path used to execute it, i.e. if you run it as `python script.py`, then it will just be "script.py". A script that depends on it needs to immediately make it a fully qualified path before the working directory is changed, e.g. `__file__ = os.path.abspath(__file__)`.

Comment: @eryksun That sounds like the problem. Nice catch, I will to do more testing to verify.

Comment: That was it. now, are there any consequences of hacking in our own `__file__`?

Comment: You don't have to modify `__file__`. You can change your code to use a different global variable -- as long as it gets set before changing the working directory.

Comment: Nice! Interested in making that an answer, so that I can accept it?